# How to open window with html or dialog box in middle view django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, dialog

I have the following scenario:
In a view I do a GET request to an external API with the data that the user provides me via form, with this GET request I get a series of images, the user then needs to write the code of the image he wants and send it to me, I need to then capture the answer and make a new GET request and finally finish my view.

Note: I cannot close my view before user interaction because I have a session object that cannot be lost, if this occurs the code entered will not actually match the image

```
            if request.POST['action'] == 'get_images':
                name = request.POST.get('name')
                birthday = request.POST.get('birthday')
                gender = request.POST.get('gender')
                preferences = preferences.Preferences(gender, birthday, name)
                preferences.login_page()
                preferences.add_page()
                images = preferences.get_images() #get images
                #need display dialog box with image in di
                response = #input user in dialog box
                resp = preferences.search_page(response)#new get to know some info user
                print(resp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following can be one method in which you do this,

Once the user enters data in the first form, send the form data via AJAX to another view in the background and then this AJAX View will call the GET Images API and send the response back.

Using this response you can open an HTML modal on click of the send button of the first form and then populate the response data from GET Images API.

The User can type in the code from this modal into your main page and then submit back to your main view. You can then handle the last bit of logic in your main view.